# NODE.JS- trying to scrape movies from IMDB using node . it does not scrape dynamically when i try to enter movie name in my console

Tags: node.js, npm-install, npm-request

```
var express = require('express');

var cheerio = require("cheerio");

var request = require("request");

var fs = require('fs');

var app = express();

app.get('/scrape/:movie' , function(req, res){

    var movie = req.params.movie;  
    option = {
        protocol : "http:",
        host: "www.imdb.com",
        pathname :"/find " ,
        search: "?q=movie",
        query: "q=movie"
    }
    var imdbUrl =url.format(option);

     request(imdbUrl,function(error,request,body){
           if(!error && response.statusCode==200)
           {
               var $ =cheerio.load(body);
               var select=$(".result_text").attr("href");
           }
     });
    urls = "http://www.imdb.com/"+ select;

    console.log(urls);

    request(urls,function(error,response,body){

     if(!error && response.statusCode==200)
     {
            var $ =cheerio.load(body);
            var title, release, rating, review;
            var json = { title : "",review : ""};

            json.title =$(".title").text(); 
            json.review= $(".reviewSection").text();
     }



      fs.writeFile('output.json',JSON.stringify(json, null, 7),function(error){
          if(!error)
               console.log('File successfully written! - Check your project directory for the output.json file');

      });

        res.send('Check your console!');
    });

});
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Actually, I am trying to scrap movie contents from IMDB . but not able to make it .  I am creating a URL dynamically and request for the find query and then use the first link and request that link to scrap the content.

Comment: You should provide some more information in your post about what you are trying to do!

Comment: Also, please reformat your code so it is all inside the code blocks.

Comment: I want to create a scrapper which scrap the user choice movie from IMDB in node application

Comment: FYI It's scrape, scraper, scraping, scraped. Not scrap/scrapper/scrapper/scrapping.